# XTR 9100 left power meter on XT 8100 crankset

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, power, xtr

Can I put a stages XTR 9100 left side power meter on a XT 8100 crankset? Seems like it should work, but haven’t found a clear yes answer.

Comment: I’ll elaborate later, but to my knowledge you can’t. XT uses the old splined interface with pinch bolts, whereas XTR uses a single-bolt thing similar to SRAM DUB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MaplePanda is correct, M8100 is incompatible with M9100.

From the Stages website (emphasis added):

SHIMANO HOLLOWTECH II MOUNTAIN BIKE

For Shimano Hollowtech II mountain bike cranks, compatibility is a bit more difficult due to changes in the left crank between versions. If you are unsure, please submit a new ticket with Stages customer support detailing your current bike and crank model.

Current models (as of Mar 2023):

- XTR M9100 12-speed: Works **only** with M9100/9120 cranksets, which do not use a pinch bolt attachment system on the left crank.
- XT M8100 12-speed: Works only with M8100, M7100, and similar 12-speed Shimano mountain cranksets that feature two pinch bolts and are 20 mm thick at the BB end. Also works with older XTR pinch bolt style cranks.

[Stages Power Meter Compatibility](https://stagescycling.com/en_us/content/power-meter-compatibility)

Answer (score 5):

Since Ted covered the main points, I shall provide some supporting information and visual aids, as promised.

The XTR FC-M9100 and -9120 cranks feature a single-bolt attachment for the left crank arm.

[image]

This mates with short, relatively large splines on the crank spindle.

[image]

---

For comparison, XT FC-M8100 and its relatives (-8120 and -8130) use the older style of left arm attachment, featuring two pinch bolts and a split.

[image]

This mates with a relatively long section of small splines.

[image]

This is the same joint design as XTR FC-M9000 and -9020.

[image]

---

Lastly, for comparison, let's examine XT FC-M8000 (also -8020). It has a wider left arm interface than both the 12 speed stuff AND the 11 speed XTR (for reference, see the gap between the pinch bolts). The difference is only a few millimeters, but that's enough to make the cranks non-interchangeable. The first image shows M8000, the second M8100.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Excellent detail. Is the reign of the two-bolt pinch on a Hollowtech II spindle coming to an end soon?  And is there an advantage to the new XTR configuration?  Questions for another post…

Comment: @TedHohl I can make some educated guesses, but no definitive conclusion as to which configuration is better/worse. Feel free to write a new question!

Comment: So is an XTR M9000 left hand crank compatible with an XT M8100 bottom bracket spindle ( I can get an XTR power meter, but not XT)? Both seem to have the same double clamp bolt design.

Comment: @PaulDarby Tentatively, I would say yes, but without having tried that actual combination I can't guarantee it.